# N word of EOF using json_encode from a SQL Query

Tags: php, mysql, json

This is a php code that retrieve de data from a SQL Query and then use json_encode

```
$app->get('/myapp/data.json', function () use($app) {
    $sql = "SELECT id, name FROM users;";

    try {
        $db = getConnection();
        $stmt = $db->query($sql);
        $results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ); 
        $db = null;
        $app->contentType("application/json; charset=utf-8");
        $app->response()->status(200);
        $app->response()->body(json_encode(array('users'=>$results)));
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo '{"error":{"text":'. $e->getMessage() .'}}';
    }
});
```

Everything ok but appears a N word in the EOF.

```
{"regiones":[{"id":"13","user":"peter"},
{"id":"14","user":"ben"},
{"id":"15","user":"harry"}]}n
```

And don't let me validate the json data

i try not using PDO (mysql_connect, mysql_select_db, mysql_query, etc) and the same, the N word in the end of the line. But i change the server and work fine. WHY???

Comment: some typo, see php file itself, see outside of php tags, etc.

Comment: You right, there was a n word after "?>" before look that i solved with a exit(), any why my mistake. Thanks